# Adding quotes around a parameter causes error?

Tags: templates, stash, parameters, email-contact-form

I have the following:

```
{exp:email:contact_form
    charset="utf-8"
    form_class="customer-email-form"
    recipients={exp:stash:get name='recipients'}
}
```

Notice that the `recipients` parameter's value is not in quotes. When I put quotes and try to send an email, I get "no recipients" error. However, if I replace the Stash with hard coded email address(es), I need the quotes to make the email form work.

Is there something wrong? Or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're running into problems with the parse order. When you add quotes, recipients becomes a valid parameter but it isn't parsed yet. When you remove the quotes, it becomes an invalid parameter and is ignored. You should be able to add `parse="inward"` to the contact_form parameters to parse recipients first.

```
{exp:email:contact_form
    charset="utf-8"
    form_class="customer-email-form"
    recipients="{exp:stash:get name='recipients'}"
    parse="inward"
}
```

There is some documentation and examples about this problem [here](https://speakerdeck.com/croxton/stash-core-principles?slide=8).